# Elasticsearch mapping for handling shirt not to match t-shirt

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am indexing a product name 'T-shirt'. My analyzer breaks 't-shirt' => 't','shirt','tshirt'.
I am using WordDelimiterFilter with catenate_words and whitespace tokenizer. But I don't want search to render 't-shirts' when queried for 'shirt' which it does. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `generate_word_parts` in your `WordDelimiterFilter` to false. It is set to true by default.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that ElasticSearch marks the strings by default to analyzed = true.
You need to modify your document to save the product name to not analyzed [This link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html) can help you with it